# Real world example where mean is multiple orders greater than the standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, mean

This question is related to my research work. As it says in the title, I wanted to know if there exist any *real world* examples where the mean is multiple orders of magnitude larger than the standard deviation?

Comment: The weight of a specific model of car?

Comment: Would [ten orders of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#Timeline) do?  This is a marginal question for our site because (1) the correct best answer is "Yes," which is too short for our format, but (2) to expand on it would generate a huge list of disparate and likely pointless examples.

Comment: Almost any manufacturing where sizes might be on the order of $1\times 10^2$ mm or so, but tolerances might be on the order of $1\times 10^{-2}$ mm will have better than four orders (since a standard deviation will tend to be a fraction of the tolerance). [Some manufactured items can have coefficients of variation below $10^{-5}$]

Comment: Measurements of the speed of light with modern techniques?